# Is this an issue with the voting navigator?

Tags: support, voting, account-suspension

During my suspension period I tested the suspension mode application, and I found some strange behavior.

When I up/down the voting navigator it says suspended members cannot vote, and it changed the count of vote to up/down. After I click that message box, it disappears, and it still shows the same upped/downed vote. After I refresh the page, it comes back to the original vote count.

Please, can you confirm?

Below are screenshots.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "aviator"? From context, it seems obvious that you're talking about the upvote and downvote buttons, but your word choice is so unusual that I feel I have to ask to be sure. Can you confirm this? The only definitions of "aviator" I know are "a person who flies planes," and "a style of wearable items similar to those worn by people who fly planes."

Comment: Did you perhaps mean vote *navigator*?

Comment: @gnostradamus ya vote navigator

Comment: @gnostradamus, good guess, I would have never thought of that. Although I'm not sure that "navigator" is a more correct, descriptive or accurate term than "aviator" in any way, in this context.

Answer (score 5):

This is by design -- all client voting is simulated (optimistically, we assume it will succeed) and the server will update in the background.

We don't really care whether the UI is 100% accurate for suspended users in this scenario.

Comment: It *should* work though -- and I can't repro this problem; the vote count is reset to the previous value when the "can't vote" message pops up.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best way to fix this is to get rid of the special case checking (ie, suspended user) and treat the user as simply a 1 rep user.  This would eliminate the need for the special case, and 1 rep users cannot upvote or downvote.

If a suspended user wonders why they can't vote, they probably have bigger problems than can be solved by telling them the reason why they can't vote, other than the results normally provided to 1 rep users.

Comment: This is actually the case, for the most part. The only difference is the actual message. So this might indeed be a bug.

Comment: @balpha : can i add one more tag as bug